# GitHub Actions - Work around required to allow referencing matrix inside the matrix

Tags: github, github-actions

GihHub Actions matrix does not allow me to reference the matrix inside itself.

For example: I need to use `matrix.platform == 'safari'` as a conditional within another matrix object, but I get the error:

*Unrecognized named-value: 'matrix'
Available expression contexts: github, inputs, vars, needs*

Does anyone have a workaround to overcome this restriction?

[image: matrix code]
[image: matrix error]